# Workaround Android's broken PRNG in Cordova/WebView

Tags: android, cordova, security, random

There is a well known bug in Android 4.2 and earlier implementation of SecureRandom that caused some people to lose their bitcoins:

https://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2013/08/some-securerandom-thoughts.html

Does it affect window.crypto.getRandomValues() in Cordova, and WebView in general? If it does, are there any workarounds?

Comment: You are using Cordova and worrying about the PRNG problem?! Cordova is IMHO not suitable for an app that requires security. It is way too complex, too many pitfalls and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My research shows that WebView is probably not affected.  window.crypto.getRandomValues() is implemented in webkit which does not use Java:

https://github.com/android/platform_external_webkit/blob/b5f8fbb89c3d48053d7e38282fd6f6aac3fdd0e6/Source/WebCore/page/Crypto.cpp#L57